# Price of copy activity in azure df

Tags: azure-data-factory, price

Hi pretty new to azure suite anyway, I’m looking to do copy activity in data factory pipeline from one azure storage container to another to be used as a backup. This will be copied every 2 weeks and the old deleted when the new is written. The pipeline carries out the copy with 167GB data read and same written based on debug details. Azure pricing says that for every 4mb that’s one operation, so 167000/4 = 41750 x 2 for read and write transactions. When put into pricing calculator I get that as being pretty cheap only like $4-5 a month with storage. Are there other costs I’m missing? Cluster costs etc.? Or have I totally missed something else. I removed iterative write operations which seem to be the most costly of ops in the calculator because I can’t see that I’m doing those in this case simply copying data with no transformations.

Any info on this would be much appreciated, found it a little difficult to fully grasp.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

when running pipeline with copy activities, the other cost you incur is related to pipeline orchestration and execution.

you can view pipeline run consumption from the monitoring section in data factory UI by clicking on the consumption link next to the pipeline run entry
[image]

that will show you the pipeline run consumption breakdown in terms of activity runs, data movement DIU-hrs and execution hrs.

for a simple copy task like you described, this cost is insignificant, but you can click on the pricing calculator link in the consumption view and play around with different scenarios to estimate the cost of  your adf pipelines
[image]